# Scala akka SSE future support

Tags: scala, akka

I am following this article https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/sse-support.html.

Now I have a function `some_def(key:String)` that returns `Future[Either[Throwable,T]]`  the `payload` for my `SSE data`

Below codebase I tried

```
(path("events") & get) {
  complete {
    Source fromFuture (some_def(key:String)) flatMapConcat {
      case Right(s: T) =>
        Source.tick(2.seconds, 2.second, NotUsed) map { _ =>
          s
        }
      case _ => Source.empty
    } map { s =>
      ServerSentEvent(
        s.message
      )
    } keepAlive (1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
    
  }
}
```

Now even though `some_def(key:String)` returns different payload post start `SSE` doesn't render that.
Is there a way we can refresh the `akka - source` .

Comment: What do you mean by `some_def` returns different data post start? The way it's written it only returns a single item once. You have to build an infinite `Source` with `repeat` or `tick` for instance.

Comment: Re-reading your code, I would just inverse the `Source.tick` and the `Source.fromFuture`.